# Fall events in Madrid

Tags: seasonal, events, madrid

I'm trying to decided when to visit Madrid during the fall.  I'd rather time this visit to correspond with interesting events.  I'm more interested in larger public city wide style events rather than simply concerts.  Are there particular canonical events I need to consider?  Are there particular resources I should consult?

As an example, Madrid has a wonderful public gay pride party, but that's summer not fall.

Comment: actually, AFAIK, there isn't much going on in fall, best events are in spring

Answer (score 3):

A good place to start for me is the [Interrail website list](http://www.interrailnet.com/countries/spain/spain-highlights). Using the info there it is easy to google on and find more detailed information. A quick google also returned [spain.info](http://www.spain.info/resultados/resultados.html?l=en&qEve=true&c2=&provincia=Madrid&municipio=&fecha=8-2012&q=) website with an events search ability for any given area of Spain, the link is for Madrid events in September.